# Allow only selected apps for sideloading in Android

Tags: android, digital-signature, android-source

I am trying to customize Android for a media device. We got the firmware from the manufacturer and it's based on Android 7 with minor modifications.

One of the things we would like to do is to restrict installation of apps on the device to certain apps only. We won't install any app store like Google Play on the device. We will build the firmware and install all apps onto the devices at our workshops and deliver to the customers. In future, we may want to install more apps on the devices via OTA or some mechanisms.

We would like to disallow customers sideloading other apps via USB port.  We created a file (eg., whitelisted_apps.txt) that has the list of all approved app names, such as -

```
com.mycompany.android.app1
com.mycompany.android.app2
com.ourpartner.android.appx
```

We tweaked the PackageInstaller app of AOSP so that when a *.APK file is opened via the file browser and when the methods in PackageInstallerActivity.java are called, it will compare the name of the app to be installed against those in whitelisted_apps.txt and if the name is not found, disallow installation of the new app. It's working.

Now, we want to improve it further because whitelisted_apps.txt can be manipulated. Some people suggest using sqlite to keep the list. We are not sure if it will be the best solution.

Some suggest using certificates and signing and we think it's a better solution than others. We will sign all the apps we want to install on the device with our key. When a *.APK file is sideloaded, the PackageInstaller will get the signature of the APK and compare against ours. If they match, the app can be sideloaded.

We followed this excellent resource: [SignatureCheck.java](https://gist.github.com/scottyab/b849701972d57cf9562e). It's working with the hardcoded APP_SIGNATURE. We have this currently:

```
public boolean validateAppSignature() throws NameNotFoundException {
    boolean sigMatch = false;
    String APP_SIGNATURE = "123456784658923C4192E61B16999";
    PackageInfo packageInfo3 = mPm.getPackageInfo(
            getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);

    try {
        for (Signature signature : packageInfo3.signatures) {
            // SHA1 the signature
            String sha1 = getSHA1(signature.toByteArray());
            Log.i(TAG, "got this SHA1 of the signature ... "+sha1);
            // check if it matches hardcoded value
            sigMatch = APP_SIGNATURE.equals(sha1);
            if (sigMatch){
                return sigMatch;  
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    return false;
}
```

Just that we don't know how to do that in a real world situation. When we build, install apps or release with OTA, we sign those apps with our private key and then on the device (PackageInstaller app), we hardcode our certificate's SHA1 signature as APP_SIGNATURE so that we can compare? Any other ideas?

Thank you so much.

Comment: "because whitelisted_apps.txt can be manipulated". It **won't** unless the device was hacked. If it was hacked no restrictions are guaranteed anymore. Anyway the signature check is way better than a static list of apps. Your signature should be assumed to remain unchanged for 20 yrs or longer, hardcoding is ok. Listing public signatures as an updatable file might be better.

Comment: Thank you. The whitelisted_apps.txt is currently in assets folder. It may have to be moved to another location because other apps/services need to access(read and write) it too so that we can update the list. So I think we can't secure it much. In any case, we will explore the signature approach and the ones Gabe Sechan suggested in the answer below and see which will be the most suitable one for us.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're trying way too hard to partially shut down sideloading.  Use a Device Owner to completely turn off installation, and just preload the apps you want.  Or make it so the only app that can install is your own downloader that only looks at your server.

Comment: Hi Gabe, thanks for your suggestions. We are worried that if we turn off installation, it may effect our OTA updates. Also, the whitelisted apps will change over time, after we deliver the devices to the customers (we may remove current apps and install new ones). In any case, I will look at your suggested solutions (I am not an Android developer) and will ask if I have more questions. Thanks once again.

Comment: All the more reason bit to do it that way. You basically need to write your own update service and fluent, and you want to pick our all installing other than through that app